# Autopopulate Fields on New Record Form

Tags: record

I have a requirement to create a follow-up task for an existing task and auto-populate field data from its parent task.

I have created another object which looks precisely like a task and created a trigger to create a task when this new object is created.

Now I to auto-populate the data from the parent task. I was wondering if it's possible.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

- If you are looking to have new follow up task button on task object record page using a out of box quick action of type create record with prepopulated field values, that is not possible on Task object.
- If you are looking to have it on any other record page, you can create a simple object specific quick action of type create a record where you can prepopulate the field values.

[image]

In Case this does not fulfill your requirement, then you can go for custom lightning component with such functionality.